# Зачем в программе высвобождать память?

Tags: c++, c

Какая объективная причина высвобождения памяти в программе ?

Нет объективных причин высвобождать память
И при грамотном проектировании программы, можно не высвобождать память, а повторно использовать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42322/discussion-on-question-by-yaroslav-----).

Answer (score 15):

Нет причин высвобождать *всю* память. Ваша цель — **программа должна бежать и не вываливаться по переполнению памяти**. Всё, что кроме этого, не так уж и важно.

Это, однако, значит, что если вы выделяете память постоянно, в цикле, то рано или поздно память исчерпается, и ваша программа упадёт. Это значит, что память, выделяемую в цикле, стоит возвращать. (Ну или не возвращать, если вас не интересует случай длительного пробега программы.)

Заметьте, что глобальные переменные — по сути выделенная и не возвращённая назад память. Точно так же любой синглтон — выделенная и не возвращённая назад память. Если вы выделяете память один или ограниченное количество раз, скорее всего её можно не возвращать назад.

Обновление: память можно и использовать повторно. Особенно просто это в C (вы выделяете пул памяти, и используете свои функции выделения для остальной части программы), в C++ несколько сложнее (вам нужен будет placement new). Это усложнит вашу программу, но может сделать её эффективнее (кастомный аллокатор часто бывает быстрее рантаймовского). При этом объём расходуемой памяти не растёт, а значит, непосредственной угрозы переполнения памяти нет.

---

Однако, обратите внимание на важный частный случай. Если вы пишете на языке, в котором освобождение памяти ещё и производит дополнительные действия (то есть, у вас есть *деструктор*), то возможно стоит освобождать память только ради этих дополнительных действий. Например, если в конструкторе вы открываете файл, а в деструкторе закрываете, то имеет смысл освобождать память, чтобы дать другим программам (или другим частям вашей программы) обращаться к этому файлу.

---

Есть и другие причины, по которым может оказаться *необходимым* освобождать память. Например, если программа занимает много адресного пространства, то при её вытеснении из оперативной памяти в файл подкачки и назад потребуется больше времени, и она будет работать медленнее с точки зрения клиента. Но это уже причины другого порядка.

---

Да, а в языках со сборщиком мусора большая часть памяти освобождается в автоматическом режиме, вам даже думать об этом не нужно.

Comment: Хм... получается, что объективной причины нет, а есть набор субъективных, которым только сам автор программы посчитает нужным уделить внимание.

Comment: @alexis031182: Ну как бы да. А и правда, зачем к каждому new по delete, кроме внутренней красоты? Если, скажем, это простая консольная утилита без циклов?

Comment: Согласен. И тут же подумал об истинной цели вопроса. Нарочно или нет.

Comment: Вопрос возник после изучения библиотеки GLib очень грамотно сделано и там нет высвобождения памяти , только повторное использование. Поэтому и возник вопрос. Есть ли действительно объективная причина высвободить память или при грамотном проектировании этого делать не нужно.

Comment: @Yaroslav: Освобождать память и снова выделять проще, чем повторно использовать (т. к. вы думаете локально: здесь нужна, взял; здесь больше не нужна, вернул), но более расходно по ресурсам (new/delete занимают время всё же, плюс глобальная блокировка кучи).

Comment: @VladD принять за ответ, что при программировании кода проще сделать код который (malloc()/free()) делает , чем повторно использует один буфер.  Возможно.

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд, объективность заключается в стремлении к тому, чтобы реализация любой программы была как можно проще, поскольку иных сложностей, которые так или иначе возникают в творческом процессе, на самом деле не так уж и мало.

Для примера можно взять хотя бы и умные указатели. Их популярность объясняется объективным нежеланием "вручную" производить корректное освобождение памяти. Ошибаться по причине невнимательности человеку свойственно, а значит тот код, что реализует особо изысканный подход, помимо того, что будет написан значительно позже, нежели чем его "умный" аналог, потребует также и дополнительного времени на проверку.

Если проект является чем-то, что не имеет конкретного срока на пути реализации и/или не влияет на финансовое благополучие разработчика, то последний может себе позволить отойти от объективной необходимости завершить свою работу в самое кратчайшее время.

Локальное выделение и освобождение памяти - это следствие объективного желания не заморачиваться и не тратить время на мелочах, которые в подавляющем большинстве задач таковыми и являются. Не сделает погоды среднестатистическому продукту использование глобального буфера и сложного менеджмента указателей с целью хранения всего подряд, если вся задача сводится к диалогу с пользователем или иному асинхронному процессу, где даже адекватность на использование многопоточности может вызвать определённые вопросы.

Стремление к сложности начинает терять поддержку в тот момент, как только относительная потеря производительности, например от использования всё тех же умных указателей или просто связки `new` - `delete`, становится менее заметна, нежели чем вполне объективное и подчас весьма заметное количество затраченных человеко-часов для разработки функционала без них.

В заключение можно придти к тому, что объективной причиной использования локального контроля за выделением памяти является вполне себе банальная практичность, которая в отдельных случаях рождается из страха от вполне себе прогнозируемого надругательства начальства над телом нерасторопного программиста.

Answer (score 5):

К вопросу о переиспользовании уже выделенной памяти - тут возникает жуткое слово ФРАГМЕНТАЦИЯ АДРЕСНОГО ПРОСТРАНСТВА.

Предположим, что программа отхватила большой блок памяти и сама в нем выделяет и освобождает блоки поменьше. В таком случае, возможна ситуация фрагментации памяти (выделили блоки 0 1 2 [забив всю память], затем блок 0 и 2 удалили).

После этого, если потребуется выделить блок, размером сразу как три ранее существовавших, без дефрагментации (что сделать крайне сложно), дальнейшая работа программы будет невозможна.

В случае работы через ОС, возможна склейка различных фрагментов физической памяти средствами MMU. У прикладной программы такой возможности нет.

Comment: Подождите, а как склейка фрагментов физической памяти поможет от фрагментации виртуального адресного пространства?

Comment: @VladD виртуальное адресное пространство при 64 разрядах адресации очень велико, благодаря этому, в нем чаще всего удается найти блок нужного размера.

Comment: Фагментация, момет который нужно учитывать , эту задачу кто то должен решать или в нутри программы или силами ОС.

Answer (score 2):

Программа должна работать правильно. Вы должны быть уверены, что программа работает правильно. Это комплексная вещь, если вы упустили один момент, то в программе ошибка, и пока вы всё не приведёте в порядок, качество программы будет низким. Для этого применяют юнит-тесты, статические проверки кода, логгирование и некоторые другие вещи. Пока вы не контролируете всю память, вы не застрахованы от ошибок. Утечка памяти сама по себе может не быть ошибкой, но это начало пути к проблемам. Если вы не написали код освобождения памяти сразу, вы рискуете не написать его никогда, а ошибку в большом проекте можно ловить месяцами, а можно не поймать вообще. Раньше была практика сразу после вызова `delete` приравнивать указатель к нулю, и потом о нём можно забыть. Сейчас есть, например, умные указатели с автоудалением. Когда вы повторно используете память(даже после освобождения), вы можете наступить на грабли в виде оставшихся старых значений(и реально будете на них наступать, когда число полей превысит сотню - за всем не уследить). Когда есть нужда в переменных на стеке, лучше создать новую, памяти хватит. Допустим, есть длинный метод, который не помещается на экране(может занимать два экрана и даже три). Вы выделяете память в первом абзаце, используете её, и намного ниже хотите использовать повторно. Тогда вы должны изучить весь код выше, чтобы выяснить, что:

- эта память удалена и занулена
- если память не удалена, в ней не осталось старых значений, которые приведут к ошибке.

Это будет тяжело и невыгодно. Проще удалить старую память, занулить её, и выделить новый указатель с новым именем. Если вы не пишете для сервера, вам утечки в виде килобайт до поры до времени могут не повредить, хотя их всё равно нужно искать. Всё равно ваша программа не будет работать больше нескольких часов(или пользователь её закроет и уйдёт по делам, или она упадёт из-за вашей ошибки, ещё она может упасть не по вашей вине).

Answer (score 0):

В программах создаваемых с использованием языков программирования с возможностью явного выделения/высвобождения памяти (С, С++, etc). Существует два подхода работы с памятью

1 Выделение памяти и ее повторное использование

- исключение ошибки "утечка памяти"
- необходимо следить за фрагминтацией памяти в программе

2 Выделение и высвобождение памяти по мере необходимости.

- возможна ошибка "утечка памяти"
- за фрагментацией памяти следит ОС

Сложность алгоритма, сложность  реализации,  "надругательства начальства над телом нерасторопного программиста" ,  это больше субектывный моменты

Answer (score 0):

Переиспользование предполагает наличие своего менеджера памяти, со своими alloc и free. Смысл делать идентичную обёртку вокруг системных механизмов? Только если однозначно будет выигрыш в производительности. Не факт что то, что вы подразумеваете под "высвобождением", действительно является этим самым высвобождением.