# Поясните пожалуйста про частый вызов malloc() и вообще

Tags: c

Имеется некая структура, скажем **my_struct**. Она нужна для декодирования JPEG картинки. В ней, также имеется поле из массива структур **c** (их 3 по цветовым плоскостям), а в этих структурах есть указатели на выходные буфера с декодированными данными по каждому цвету (Y, Cr и Cb). Код не мой и я его приспосабливаю для камеры, а там непрерывный поток этих JPEG картинок. В коде есть **постоянное**(при декодировании) выделение памяти под эти выходные буфера:

```
c->pixels = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
```

Их размеры (size) 921600, 230400 и 230400 байт. После выделения памяти (строка выше) - они заполняются 0x80:

```
memset(c->pixels, 0x80, size);
```

Это заполнение занимает в среднем 2, 0.5 и 0.5 мс для каждой цв. плоскости. Причем (!) если убрать это заполнение (убрать этот memset), то время декодирования наоборот увеличивается (!) где-то на 3 мс. Я так думаю, что тут уже вступает в работу кэш и поэтому имеем наоборот увеличение времени декодирования. Я не зря Вам пояснил эти нюансы с неожиданными увеличениями времени декодирования потому что это, как увидите, как раз имеет непосредственное отношение к вопросу темы. А теперь мой вопрос - "Если постоянно вызывать этот **malloc** для буферов, то не страшно ли это? В смысле насчет постоянного выделения памяти под одни и те же буфера. Причем, они выделяются вроде всегда по одним и тем же адресам. Видимо ф. malloc() как-то "продумывает" все мои выходки в коде. Как же она работает - эта malloc()? И все-таки посоветуете убрать этот постоянное динамическое выделение кода для вых. буферов? Или ничего страшного в этом постоянном динамическом выделении памяти нет?"
Главная структура my_struct тоже вначале кода обнуляется:

```
memset(my_struct, 0, sizeof(my_struct));
```

Обнуление этой структуры нужно для дальнейшей правильной работы этого декодировщика. Оно занимает сравнительно мало времени (где-то 55-56 мкс) и если его убрать, то нужно многое менять в коде чтобы правильно потом работало. И я оставил это обнуление главной структуры. Соответсвенно пока остаются эти динам. выделения памяти под вых. буфера.

Comment: Вообще `malloc()` это стиль C. В C++ как правило вместо него идет `new`

Comment: Там, в том коде, "смесь" C и C++. Это т.н. ujpeg. А я потому и отметил в тегах C++ и пр. что хочу  все-таки одно что оставить, а не такую смесь. Спасибо.

Comment: Ради интереса и если есть время и пр. - посмотрите код этого "ujpeg"-а (там всего 2 файла). Можно ужаснуться сколько там таких "стилевых" ошибок, но работает и главное - нелохо (вроде). Я уже значительную часть того кода перевел под "нормальный" C++ класс, методы и пр. Но остались пока что некоторые вопросы в т.ч., что здесь спросил.

Comment: Ради интереса заменил на такое: c->pixels = new unsigned char[size]; И вроде, блин, на 0.5мс уменьшилось время декодирования (??). Но все равно лучше переделать как Harry посоветовал - убрать динам. выделения. Много переделывать просто придется т.к. от обнуления главной структуры нужно отказаться вначале. Каша там в том коде этого ujpeg-а.

Comment: Нет показалось и никаких изменений написанное на "стиле C++" c->pixels = new unsigned char[size]; не дает (и не должно по логике давать).

Comment: Вобще вопрос по [высвобождению памяти задавался](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542141/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c) , объективного ответа,  не нашлось .

Comment: Yaroslav, то что доктор прописал. Не знаю как тут "+" именно за этот ответ поставить (если знаете - подскажите если не влом). Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 7):

Первый и глобальный совет в [Optimized C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920038030.do) - убрать как можно больше, и использовать как можно меньше обращений к менеджеру динамической памяти, т.е. все эти `malloc`, `realloc` и прочие `free`.

Я бы на вашем месте выделил эти буфера - раз они многократно выделяются и освобождаются - один раз, и использовал их, пока нужны, а удалял уже по окончании всей работы.

И, само собой, сравнил бы время работы и насколько это изменение влияет на всю скорость работы программы - может, совсем не это место является узким.

Comment: Большое спасибо за правильный толчок (пинок). Значит все-таки лучше избавиться от постоянного malloc() и пр. Насчет сравнения времени работы - постоянно делаю (gporf и врем. отметки) и уже уперся в то что по "мелочам" (malloc(), memset как тут) пытаюсь дальше сооптимизировать работу. А главный bottleneck это вообще-то декодирование Хаффмана, но там вроде до предела оптимизации дошел. Никак у меня не получилось распараллелить это декодирование Хаффмана - сколько вариантов алгоритмов/кодов не перепробовал (в т.ч. на OpenCL ). Смирился, что тут декодирование по Хаффману идет в одном потоке.

Comment: Можно сказать не избавится, а не вызывать циклически (без необходимости). В случае с jpg часто используют memory pool (pooling) - создают пулы памяти - условно как кеш результатов работы malloc. Кешировать результаты проще, чуть сложнее организовывать пулы самому. Есть наверное уже написаные библиотеки пулов.

Comment: Огромное спасибо nick_n_a Вам за комментарий! Хотя он не совсем по теме вроде, но очень интересен. Надо бы мне посмотреть по этому способу что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя накладные расходы на malloc обычно велики, при выделении такого большого куска памяти, как правило, они пренебрежимо малы, в сравнении с работой, которая будет произведена над этим куском.

Один и тот-же адрес памяти, памяти выдается, скорее всего, потому что это единственный непрерывный свободный блок памяти. (Никаким другим частям программы, столько памяти одним блоком не понадобилось.) Никакой скрытой логики функции malloc приписывать не надо.

Для начала, я бы проверил профайлером, какие части программы действительно расходуют время. 
Если профайлер на данной платформе недоступен, временно выделил статические массивы, благо размер известен, и использовал их. Если это не даст существенного прироста производительности - вернул malloc, если даст - экспериментировать с пользовательскими аллокаторами.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Но я спросил с точки зрения этого постоянного вызова malloc() и скажем так десятки-сотни-миллионы раз. Пока работает камера. Нет тут ничего страшного? Грубо говоря, память не "зассорится" в итоге? Или не дефрагментируется когда-нибудь за такое большое кол-во вызовов этой malloc()?

Comment: @AleksBak Ну, если вызовы одни и те же - то не засорится... но сотни миллионов раз вызывать malloc/free просто бессмысленно!