# Обязательно ли очищать память перед выходом из программы?

Tags: c, память

Например:

```
char **twoarray = (char **) malloc(2 * sizeof(char *)); // выделено
*(twoarray + 0) = (char *) malloc((1 + 1) * sizeof(char)); // выделено
*(twoarray + 1) = (char *) malloc((1 + 1) * sizeof(char)); // не выделено

if (*(twoarray + 1) == NULL) {
    free(*(twoarray + 0)); // очистка
    free(twoarray); // очистка
    exit(-1);
}
```

Просто, когда работаешь с трёхмерными массивами ещё и в цикле, то очищать становится сложнее..

Comment: Для вас, на даном этапе, не обязательно. Память очистится в результате "завершения работы программы". Важна очистка у долгоработающих больших программ.

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542141/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c) уже был.

Comment: Язык Си не дает (да и не может дать) ответа на этот вопрос. Что произойдет, если не освобождать памяти, целиком и полностью зависит от окружения, в котором выполняется программа.

Answer (score 12):

В принципе не обязательно. Тем более в C, где удаление памяти не связано автоматически с вызовом деструктора.

И тем не менее пару причин есть. Во-первых, для выращивания в себе хорошей привычки - *поигрался - положи на место*. А во-вторых, а вдруг в будущем этот `exit(1)` превратится всего лишь в `return` в новой версии? Вспомните ли вы тогда, что там должно быть освобождено?

Answer (score 2):

Хоть операционная система и высвобождает память и прочие ресурсы при уничтожении адресного пространства процесса, **обязательность возврата памяти нужна в случае профилирования утечек памяти**.

Дело в том, что у ОС нет возможности определить, какие участки памяти оставили умышленно, для оптимизации, а какие остались случайно, из-за потери указателей на них. Поэтому отсутствие очистки перед выходом сильно засоряет отладочный вывод, из-за чего можно пропустить действительно важную запись об утечке.

Answer (score -1):

Не очищать память - плохой стиль программирования, так как утечка памяти может привести к плохим последствиям( Капитан очевидность)

Comment: Не ответ на вопрос, куда память утечёт при выходе из программы?

Comment: она остается в куче и будет там висеть

Comment: Хм, не подскажете, в каких операционных системах куча не освобождается автоматически при выходе из программы?

Comment: Во всех освобождается, а с чего такой вопрос? Я имел ввиду, что происходит переполнение памяти, и программа может быть остановлена

Comment: Как переполнение памяти может случиться при выходе? o_O

Comment: не при выходе, а при исполнении

Comment: Вопрос не про исполнение, а про выход