# Очистка многомерного массива перед принудительным выходом из программы, СИ

Tags: c, массивы, malloc

Здравствуйте, помогите решить проблему. Проблема заключается в очистке 
 многомерного массива перед выходом в случае не выделения памяти. Я уже задавал подобный вопрос об очистке перед выходом, многие рекомендуют не полагаться на OS, а очищать самому, но у меня возникла проблема. Нужно очистить весь многомерный массив, но у меня не хватает "ума" реализовать очистку. Если в первом и во втором случае - можно подумать и реализовать очистку, то в третьем сложно. В C_ONE и C_TWO может быть, например, любое число, это лишь пример.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define C_ONE 2
#define C_TWO 2

int
main(void)
{
    char ***test = NULL;

    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < C_ONE; i++) {
        test = (char ***) realloc((i + 1) * sizeof(char **));

        if (test == NULL) {
            // тут всё просто
            if (i > 0) {
                for (unsigned char j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    for (unsigned char k = 0; k < C_TWO; k++)
                        free(*(*(test + j) + k));

                    free(*(test + j));
                }

                free(test);
            }

            exit(-1);
        }

        *(test + i) = (char **) malloc(C_TWO * sizeof(char *));

        if (*(test + i) == NULL) {
            /**
            * Хорошо, а тут как "всё" очистить?
            **/
            exit(-1);
        }

        for (unsigned char m = 0; m < C_TWO; m++) {
            *(*(test + i) + m) = (char *) malloc((1 + 1) * sizeof(char));

            if (*(*(test + i) + 0) == NULL) {
                /**
                * Если во втором случае можно подумать и написать,
                * тогда в этом уже сложно.
                **/
                exit(-1);
            }

            strcpy(*(*(test + i) + m), "W");
        }
    }

    // если всё успешно, то очистка, как и в первом случае.
    for (unsigned char m = 0; m < C_ONE; m++) {
        for (unsigned char o = 0; o < C_TWO; o++)
            free(*(*(test + m) + o));

        free(*(test + m));
    }

    free(test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит **очистка**? Если это освобождение памяти,то можете не беспокоится, вся выделенная память после завершения приложения вернется в систему.

Comment: @tilin """Я уже задавал подобный вопрос об очистке перед выходом, многие рекомендуют не полагаться на OS, а **очищать самому,**"""

Comment: Я уже [писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/717855/208074), что прибираться необходимо как минимум при запуске программы под профилировщиком, чтобы не засорять журнал утечек.

Comment: @Arhad я прибираюсь перед выходом, но если при выделении ничего не выделится, то программа крашнится. Я пытаюсь это контролировать, как выше показано. Очистка не проблема, но когда это заходит вот настолько, то сложно очистить, да ещё и в цикле.

Comment: Начнём с того, что вы несогласованно выделяете и высвобождаете память. Судя по указателям, вы хотите массив массивов массивов, но память выделяете сплошным одноуровневым куском. А высвобождаете его всё-таки как исходно задуманный массив массивов массивов.

Comment: @Arhad Увы, но другого варианта выделения я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что вы зачем то пытаетесь очистить все уровни массива ещё при неудаче в выделении самого верхнего уровня.

Во-вторых, успешность выделения памяти необходимо проверять ещё в самом начале, чтобы аварийно прервать работу при неудаче.

Теперь приступим к исправлению. Для начала воспользуемся принципом модульности и вынесем выделение и освобождение памяти в отдельные функции:

```
char*** allocate();
void deallocate(char** array);
```

Реализуем выделение памяти:

```
// Размерности массива
#define X_COUNT 5
#define Y_COUNT 2
#define Z_COUNT 8

char*** allocate()
{
    // Пытаемся выделить верхний уровень
    char*** const array = (char***)malloc(X_COUNT * sizeof(char**));

    // Если выделение успешно, заполняем второй уровень, иначе прерываемся
    if(array)
    {
        // Заполняем массив, пока не дойдём до конца, либо не поймаем ошибку.
        // И да, я считаю трюки типа while(true) + break вводящими в заблуждение,
        // так что воспользуемся флагом.
        bool metError = false;
        size_t xId, yId;
        for(xId = 0; xId < X_COUNT && !metError; ++xId)
        {
            // Пытаемся выделить массив второй размерности
            array[xId] = (char**)malloc(Y_COUNT * sizeof(char*));
            if(array[xId])
            {
                for(yId = 0; yId < Y_COUNT && !metError; ++yId)
                {
                    // Пытаемся выделить обнулённый массив третьей размерности
                    array[xId][yId] = calloc(Z_COUNT, sizeof(char));
                    if(!array[xId][yId])
                        metError = true;
                }
            }
            else
                metError = true;
        }

        // Если встретили ошибку — откатываем всё, что успели выделить,
        // включая первый уровень.
        //
        // Собственно, для определения позиции окончания успешного заполнения
        // xId и yId и были вынесены наружу, чтобы стать доступными отсюда.
        if(metError)
        {
            // Первые xId строк массива были успешно выделены целиком
            for(size_t x = 0; x < xId; ++x)
            {
                for(size_t y = 0; y < Y_COUNT; ++y)
                    free(array[x][y]);
                free(array[x]);
            }

            // Последняя же выделенная строка оборвалась на выделении yId-го
            // столбца
            for(size_t y = 0; y < yId; ++y)
                free(array[xId][y]);
            free(array[xId]);

            free(array);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
            return array;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Высвобождение же гораздо проще. Никаких проверок не требуется, просто проход по обеим уровням

```
void deallocate(char*** array)
{
    for(xId = 0; xId < X_COUNT; ++xId)
    {
        for(yId = 0; yId < Y_COUNT; ++yId)
            free(array[xId][yId]);
        free(array[xId]);

    }
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: это понятно. но у меня проблема с трёхмерным массивом. И почему вы решили, что судя по `C_ONE` и `C_TWO` - это выделение для двумерного? вот простая форма того же, что показано у меня в вопросе `char test[2][2][3] = {{{'1', '2', '\0'}, {'3', '4', '\0'}}, {{'5', '6', '\0'}, {'7', '8', '\0'}}};` то есть вывод будет таков `fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", test[0][0]); // 12` , но дело вовсе не в этом, выделяя память для самого последнего уровня `test[1][1]` , например, память может не выделится, а значит нужно очистить `test[1][0]`, затем `test[1]`, затем `test[0][1]`, затем `test[0][0]` и затем `test[0]`

Comment: то есть нужно очистить всё то, что осталось за `test[1][1]` или того массива, для которого память  не выделилась.. `C_ONE` и `C_TWO` могут содержать любое число, 2 - это пример, поэтому нужно, чтобы программа сама знала, что нужно очистить всё, что было выделено до `test[1][1]` , например

Comment: @ast, исправил на трёхмерный случай. И ещё, если `C_ONE` и `C_TWO` это не размерности, то что они делают в выражениях определения размера выделяемой памяти для `malloc`-а?

Comment: `C_ONE` и `C_TWO` - это как пример, большое спасибо за ответ. Сейчас постараюсь разобрать и вставить в свой код)

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю, у вас это точно массив? Вот вы говорите что C_ONE и C_TWO могут содержать любое число и это таки понятно, непонятно только что вам мешает зная размерности массива вычислить необходимый для него объем памяти и выделить его одним блоком? Это будет не только проще но и эффективней.

Comment: @ДмитрийЕвгеньевичХоличев, `у вас это точно массив` — да, так называемый jagged array. `выделить его одним блоком` —согласен, можно было бы ограничиться созданием двух больших массивов (собственно данных типа `char` и указателей `char*` на промежуточных уровнях). Но моей задачей было исправление именно имеющегося кода (чтобы не запутать вопрошающего). Однако вы можете опубликовать свои соображения отдельным ответом (и собирать за него плюсы).